# Does a singular noun after the word "between" need an article?

Tags: articles

Does a singular noun after the word "between" need an article?

For example in the following interrogative sentence:

> What is the difference between **a** word to sentence?

I am not sure if I need to put here an article (where I emphasized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, we do not use *to* in this construction, but *and*:

> What is the difference between A **and** B?

Beyond that, what article (or other determiner) you use with A and B depends on the discourse context; the use of *difference between* is irrelevant:

- A and B may take determiners of the same category or different categories.
- If A (or B) has been specifically identified in the discourse, or is familiar to your hearers, you use *the* or some other definite determiner; if it has not been identified, or if no specific entity is intended, use *a* or some other indefinite determiner.

> What is the difference between a job and a profession? ... *Both* job *and* profession *designate any member, not a specific member, of that category.*
>
> What is the difference between the job we have just described and a profession? ... Job *designates an identified specific entity,* profession *designates any member of that category.*
>
> What is the difference between the pronoun in example A and the pronoun in example B? ... *Both pronouns are identified specific entities.
>
> What is the difference between the job John holds and the job of his CEO? ... *Both* jobs *are identified specific entities*.

There are of course many other rules—for instance, proper nouns are inherently determinate and take no article—but they're all the same rules that apply in any other situation.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you well you're saying that I should you an article always after "between" (I didn't ask about the type of article, generally I know how to use them. a/an for indefinite or the for definite). That's right?

Comment: @Assiduous There's no particular rule with *between*: just whatever other rules are relevant.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but in the bottom line I really don't understand the answer. Should I say "what is the difference between a donkey and a horse" or can I say "what is the difference between donkey and horse"?

Comment: @Assiduous Ordinarily we use *a* here, just as we would in asking *What is a donkey/horse*; but *What is the difference between butter and margarine?*, just as you would ask "What is butter?"

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand :)